# Unity Firebase как отправить Dictionaty

Tags: firebase, словари

пытаюсь отправить данные и Dictionaty через firebase, изначально были разные варианты Dictionary<string, (int, uint, string  и т.д.)>. При отправки на сервер, ошибок нет и данные сохраняются, но только словари никак не передаются. Погуглив нашёл что firebase работает только с
Dictionary<string, object>, переделал и отправил, результат тот же. Есть какой то способ для отправки словарей или нужно какие-то костыли изобретать?